# Http redirect 302 with regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess, http, redirect, http-status-code-302

I need to make 302 redirection but I'm not able to achieve it, regex is just beyond my comprehension :(

What I need to achieve:

Original URL: www.original.com/**out**/string1/string2/string3/?id=1

Target URL: **this**.**target**.com/string1/string2/string3/?id=1&**extra=5**

I highlited problematic parts - all of them stay the same in all redirects so they can be hardcoded.

```
EDIT: I need to put it to htaccess
```

Anybody can help me with this?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /out/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/\?id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://this.target.com/%1/%2/%3/?id=%4&extra=5 [NE,L,R=302]
```

Comment: It works, it just doesnt change target website url to this.target.com and also you hardcoded id=1 that can vary. Could you please add it to your code? Many thanks!

Comment: @Pupik I edited my answer as per your comment. please reload the page to see it.